# How can I represent polymorphism in JMX?

Tags: java, polymorphism, jmx

I have some types like this:

```
public interface Numbering {
    List<NumberingComponent> getComponents();
}

public interface NumberingComponent {
    Object getValue();
}

public interface StringNumberingComponent extends NumberingComponent {
    String getValue();
}

public interface IntegerNumberingComponent extends NumberingComponent {
    Integer getValue();
}
```

This is all well and good, unless you try to register an MXBean which happens to use this type, and you get:

```
...top of exception chain omitted ...
Caused by: javax.management.openmbean.OpenDataException: Cannot convert type: class com.acme.NumberingComponent
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter.openDataException(OpenConverter.java:1411)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter.toConverter(OpenConverter.java:264)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter.makeArrayOrCollectionConverter(OpenConverter.java:315)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter.makeParameterizedConverter(OpenConverter.java:393)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter.makeConverter(OpenConverter.java:296)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter.toConverter(OpenConverter.java:262)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: javax.management.openmbean.OpenDataException: Cannot convert type: interface java.io.Serializable
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter.openDataException(OpenConverter.java:1411)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter.toConverter(OpenConverter.java:264)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter.makeCompositeConverter(OpenConverter.java:467)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter.makeConverter(OpenConverter.java:293)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter.toConverter(OpenConverter.java:262)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: javax.management.openmbean.OpenDataException: Can't map java.io.Serializable to an open data type
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter.makeCompositeConverter(OpenConverter.java:454)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter.makeConverter(OpenConverter.java:293)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.OpenConverter.toConverter(OpenConverter.java:262)
    ... 64 more
```

Strings and integers are representable in JMX but Object isn't, as at least one getter needs to be present on the class for it to recognise it as a usable type.  I know that any attempt to add an abstraction layer in is not going to help, because NumberingComponent itself is already such a layer.  The original version of the interfaces had generics in there as well, but I removed them to keep it simpler, and it fails in the same way with or without them.

Is there some other way I can go about mapping this to a composite type?  I googled the exception message, and got essentially no hits at all. (!!)

Comment: Can you show the actual class you are registering.  JMX is going to use reflection on the class, not the interfaces, right?  Are you sure that your interface hierarchy is really the problem here?

Comment: It's actually reflecting on the interfaces, it seems.  I know that it's using the actual class declarations because it is discovering List<Thing> and realising that it needs to check how to convert Thing (this wouldn't be present at runtime.)

Answer (score 1):

You could make StringNumberingComponent and IntegerNumbering interfaces also extend [CompositeDataView](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/management/openmbean/CompositeDataView.html). Assuming the MBean's MBeanInfo indicates the correct CompositeType for the attribute, the MBeanServer will "render" the attribute as a CompositeData instance which will serialize correctly.

The method the concrete implementations will need to implement is fairly straightforward since your CompositeType will only have one field:

```
public CompositeData toCompositeData(CompositeType ct)
```

There's a decent example in the [JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/management/openmbean/CompositeDataView.html).